# Undefined function sensing

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying to do this (is this possible?) with GCC compiler:

Specifiy a function but this function if is not implemented point to a NULL. Example:

```
extern void something(uint some);
```

And if this is unimplemented point to a NULL value.

So it's possible check like this:

```
something != NULL ? something(222) : etc.;
```

I would like solution with trough GCC (this could be solvable with function pointers).

Comment: The compiler is irrelevant; you care about the linker.  Perhaps you want to attempt a `dlopen` and  `dlsym`: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/dl-libraries.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is definitely not portable, but gcc can do this with weak symbols on some platforms. I know this works on Linux and *BSD, but doesn't work on MacOS.

```
$ cat weak.c
#include <stdio.h>

extern int foo(void) __attribute__((__weak__));

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int x = foo ? foo() : 42;

    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
$ cat weak2.c
int
foo(void)
{
    return 17;
}
$ cc -o weak weak.c && ./weak
42
$ cc -o weak weak.c weak2.c && ./weak
17
$
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using GCC's [weakref](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bweakref_007d-attribute-3034) attribute:

```
extern void something(int);
static void something_else(int) __attribute__((weakref("something")));

int main()
{
  if (something_else)
    something_else(122);
}
```

If `something` is not defined in the program then the weak alias `something_else` will have an address of zero. If `something` is defined, `something_else` will be an alias for it.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you are trying to get the compiler to locate a function at the memory address 0 (`NULL`). This cannot be done in C without platform/compiler specific constructs.

One question though, is why you would ever want to do this. C is a static language, so if you know that the function will never exist during compilation you might as well just use the pre-processor to tell the rest of the program about this at compile time. Indeed these sorts of compile time substitutions are precisely why the preprocessor is there in the first place.

I would create a macro that you define if your function exists as follows:

`#define THE_SOMETHING_FUNCTION_EXISTS`

Then replace anywhere you would have tested for `something == NULL` with an `#ifdef` instead.

Of course, if the function’s existence might change at run-time then the correct way to implement the behaviour you want is to make `something` a function pointer.