# Why does GCC's threading standard library implementation throw exceptions if you don't include pthread?

Tags: c++, pthreads, c++14

When I write code that uses, for example, `std::promise`, and I don't include the PThread library in GCC, I get an exception thrown rather than a linker error. For example:

```
void product(std::promise<int> intPromise, int a, int b)
{
    intPromise.set_value(a * b);
}
int main()
{
    int a = 20;
    int b = 10;
    std::promise<int> prodPromise;
    std::future<int> prodResult = prodPromise.get_future();
    product(std::move(prodPromise), a, b);
    std::cout << "20*10= " << prodResult.get() << std::endl;
}
```

If I compile this code without `-pthread`, the following exception is thrown:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Unknown error -1
Aborted (core dumped)
```

If `std::promise` using the `pthread` library internally, then it should throw linkage error right if I don't give the `-pthread` commandline option to `g++`. But it's compiling without any errors and while running I am getting the above issue.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: He's asking (thought it takes way too long to get to the point) why it throws exceptions rather than fails to link entirely.

Comment: libstdc++ has a pluggable threads implementation ([gthreads](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_concurrency_impl.html)). The pluggability is handled at run time.

Comment: Well, I can explain [how](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libgcc/gthr-posix.h#L252), but still would be nice to know why.

Comment: `clang++` + `libc++` [works fine](https://godbolt.org/z/jxGf-i). Bug in `libstdc++`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, not a bug, but an implementation detail.

Comment: @Evg Ah, I see. Nice answer below!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is that `libstdc++` uses the so called [weak references](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bweakref_007d-attribute-3034).

We can easily trace why your particular code example throws an exception. `set_value()` calls `std::call_once`. That function in its implementation has [the line](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/releases/gcc-8/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/mutex#L684)<sup>*</sup>:

```
int e = gthread_once(&once.M_once, &once_proxy);
```

where `gthread_once` [is](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/releases/gcc-8/libgcc/gthr-posix.h#L695):

```
static inline int gthread_once(gthread_once_t *once, void (*func)(void))
{
  if (gthread_active_p())
    return ...
  else
    return -1;
}
```

`gthread_active_p` returns `false`, that's why `gthread_once` returns `-1`, which is mentioned in the exception string.

Now let's [take a look](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/releases/gcc-8/libgcc/gthr-posix.h#L235) at `gthread_active_p`:

```
static __typeof(pthread_key_create) gthrw_pthread_key_create
    __attribute__ ((weakref("__pthread_key_create")));

static inline int gthread_active_p(void)
{
  static void *const gthread_active_ptr = (void *)&gthrw_pthread_key_create;
  return gthread_active_ptr != 0;
}
```

`gthrw_pthread_key_create` is a [weak reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29210611) to `__pthread_key_create`. If there is no symbol `__pthread_key_create` found by the linker, `&gthrw_pthread_key_create` will be a null pointer, if `__pthread_key_create` is found, `gthrw_pthread_key_create` will be an alias for it. `__pthread_key_create` is exported by the `pthreads` library.

The standard library source code also [contains](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/releases/gcc-8/libgcc/gthr-posix.h#L214) the following comment:

> For a program to be multi-threaded the only thing that it certainly must be using is `pthread_create`. However, there may be other libraries that intercept `pthread_create` with their own definitions to wrap `pthreads` functionality for some purpose. In those cases, `pthread_create` being defined might not necessarily mean that `libpthread` is actually linked in.
>
> For the GNU C library, we can use a known internal name. This is always available in the ABI, but no other library would define it. That is ideal, since any public `pthread` function might be intercepted just as `pthread_create might be`. `__pthread_key_create` is an "internal" implementation symbol, but it is part of the public exported ABI. Also, it's among the symbols that the static `libpthread.a` always links in whenever `pthread_create` is used, so there is no danger of a false negative result in any statically-linked, multi-threaded program.

---

<sup>*</sup> Some underscores are removed and macros are expanded to improve readability.